# lightweight way to use member functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda, member

I am new to C++. I have encountered a problem with member functions and hope to find a lightweight or appropriate solution.

I have a Data class. And many Work classes that inherit the same parent class. They all have 2 methods, pull and push. Now I hope to construct an OperationFlow class to optimize the calculation. Therefore, it is necessary to abstract an Operation class, and each instance of it contains a certain method of a certain work class instance.

```cpp
class Data;
class Work_Base;
class Work1:public Work_Base{
public:
    Data pull(Data);
    Data push(Data);
}
class Work2:public Work_Base{
// similar as Work1
}
// and so on;

class Operation{ // I want to realize, not real code
public:
    auto f; 
    Work w; //It is OK to have or not to have this member;
    Operation(Work w, auto f):w(w),f(f){};
    Data run(Data d){return w.f(d)};
}

class OperationFlow{ //Not the focus of this topic
public:
    vector<Operation> ops;
}
```

In fact, I have realized the Operation class by std::function<Data(Data)>, see below. However, it may be heavyweight, so I hope to find a lightweight or appropriate alternative.

```cpp
typedef std::function<Data(Data)> DF;
class Operation{
public:
    DF f; // f is lambda function that captures work object, so no work object member needed;
    Operation(DF f):f(f){};
    Data run(Data d){return f(d)};
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe ask yourself first: is 'may be heavyweight' really a good enough reason to change something which works? Do you have any proof it hinders your application's performance in any way?

Comment: Well, another option is to make `run` a template and take a lambda directly. As in `template<class Function> Data run(Data d, Function f) { f(d); }` which will skip `std::function`.

Comment: The purpose of using the operations class is to optimize the calculation, so efficiency is very important. I don't know how to implement non-std::function, so I can't compare them. But tested on functions, using function pointers is 3 times faster than using std::function. But it seems that member functions cannot be implemented through function pointers.

Comment: Define "efficiency"? Do you have a *measurable performance problem*? Are you instantiating billions of these objects? Probably not. You're throwing around terms like "lightweight" and "heavyweight" as if `std::function` is somehow computationally expensive to create. It really isn't, especially not if you're creating a handful of them in the lifespan of the program.

Comment: Remember the "cost" of an object is generally a factor of how many properties it has and how big those are, in other words `sizeof(Operation)` times how many you're allocating is the net cost. These examples have very few properties so they're by no means "heavyweight".

Comment: Comparing one thing against another and ignoring how it's actually used in an application is not too interesting. By example: by your claim suppose std::function overhead is 3uSec and a bare pointer's 'just' 1 uSec. But the calculations done in the actual function take 100mSec. Now does the overhead of std::function still matter?

Comment: It sounds like you're vaguely hinting at the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) here as an alternative to just putting things in the class. Both approaches are valid. It really depends on the long-term goals.

Comment: @DeiDei I hope to include Work member function as Operation's member in advance, cause the operation would run after they are combined as an OperationFlow.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I will ponder it.